# How to list all the uncommented PostgreSQL columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm documenting the schema of a database using the PostgreSQL built-in [comment](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-comment.html) capabilities. At some point I forgot to comment some columns but I'm not sure which ones.

Is there a way to list all the columns in a schema that are not commented ? 
That would be very helpful to be able to end commenting all the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. To do so, you need to find out all the columns in the schema that are not listed in the `pg_description`. You can start listing all the column comments in the database:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM pg_description
WHERE  objsubid > 0;
```

```
objoid | classoid | objsubid | description
-------|----------|----------|------------
68258  | 1259     | 10       | The number of individual Devices used in the exposure.
68258  | 1259     | 11       | A key to the provider who administered the...
```

> Column `objsubid` refers to the column order in a table, if the row
>   object is a column, for all other object types, `objsubid` is zero.

Then find all the columns in a schema, by checking the `informataion_schema.columns` relation:

```sql
SELECT
  (cols.table_schema || '.' || cols.table_name)::regclass, 
  cols.table_name, 
  cols.column_name, 
  cols.ordinal_position
FROM 
  information_schema.columns AS cols 
WHERE 
  cols.table_schema = 'my_schema';
```

```
table_name | column_name  | ordinal_position | oid
-----------|--------------|------------------|----
concept    | concept_id   | 1                | 67630
concept    | concept_name | 2                | 67630
```

The `ordinal_position` column refers to the position of the column within the table, the same position `objsubid` references to. The statement `(cols.table_schema || '.' || cols.table_name)::regclass` creates a string representation of the table (Ex. `my_schema.my_table`) that points the [internal Postgres identifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html), which is the same identifier as `objoid` in the `pg_description` table.

Finally, doing a `LEFT JOIN` on `pg_description` results in the uncommented columns emerge. **Remember to change the `table_schema` to your schema.** Alternatively you can just ignore internal uncommented stuff with `cols.table_schema != 'pg_catalog' AND cols.table_schema != 'information_schema'`.

```sql
SELECT
   column_name,
   table_name
FROM (
    SELECT
        cols.table_name,
        cols.column_name,
        cols.ordinal_position,
        (cols.table_schema || '.' || cols.table_name)::regclass AS table_oid
    FROM information_schema.columns AS cols
    WHERE cols.table_schema = 'my_schema'
) AS column_table_oid
LEFT JOIN pg_description 
    ON pg_description.objsubid = column_table_oid.ordinal_position
    AND pg_description.objoid = column_table_oid.table_oid
WHERE 
    pg_description.objoid IS NULL
    AND pg_description.objsubid IS NULL;
```